livesmart server video php file not working on local
I have windows 10. I am using Laragon having Apache, php, mysql etc. I have Node js, npm, maria DB etc installed as well. I am trying to setup “livesmart server video” from https://codecanyon.net/item/livesmart-allin-one-bundle/48456060 on my local.
I hit this https://localhost/livesmart_server_video/public/install/, filled relevant information. As per success message, I executed bash script and also updated conf file of virtual host.
http://localhost:9002/ location worked fine, but when I click on “start new meeting” then http://localhost:9002/server/script.php gives 404 error so pages with Node.js working fine, but it is not routing PHP requests through Apache.
If I directly replace server/script.php with https://localhost/livesmart_server_video/public/server/script.php in public\js\bundle.js, public\dash\footer.php then URL works but in response, I get error

Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Origin)

what is the solution? How Apache and Node.js can work simultaneously? Apache for PHP files and Node.js for JS files
